# Difference between IN and JOIN

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I was wondering what was the difference between the two queries mentioned below, because the first one takes more than 10 seconds to execute on the server and the second one executes in less than one second...

**UPDATE - I**
Here are the actual queries and their Execution Plans as copied and pasted from SQL Server (as is), sorry for any inconvenience caused by my previous queries... :(

```
SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), m.PlanDate, 106), ' ', '-') AS ManagmentPlanDate
FROM    ManagmentPlan m
        INNER JOIN Product p ON p.Product_ID = m.ProductID
        INNER JOIN Category c ON c.C_ID = p.C_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee e ON e.emp_no = m.PrescribedBy
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Issue_Stock i ON i.serial_no = m.IssueStockID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Units u ON u.U_ID = p.U_ID
WHERE   ( ( @PatientID IS NULL )
          AND ( @VisitID IS NULL )
          AND ( m.WardRegNo = @WardRegNo )
        )
        OR --Get only cuurent admission TP 
        ( ( @PatientID IS NULL )
          AND ( @WardRegNo IS NULL )
          AND ( VisitID = @VisitID
                AND m.WardRegNo IS NULL
              )
        )
        OR -- Get Only Current OPD visit TP 
        ( ( @WardRegNo IS NULL )
          AND ( @VisitID IS NULL )
          AND ( visitid IN ( SELECT id
                             FROM   PatientVisit
                             WHERE  PatientID = @PatientID ) )
        )
        OR --Get All Visits TP
        ( ( @PatientID IS NULL )
          AND ( @VisitID IS NOT NULL )
          AND ( @WardRegNo IS NOT NULL )
          AND ( ( VisitID = @VisitID )
                OR ( m.WardRegNo = @WardRegNo )
              )
        ) -- Get Current OPD visit and cuurent admission TP (Both)
        AND m.Deleted != 1
        AND m.PatientDeptID = @PatientDeptID
GROUP BY REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), m.PlanDate, 106), ' ', '-')
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), m.PlanDate, 106), ' ', '-') AS DATETIME) DESC
```

[image: Execution Plan of the first Query]

and

```
SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), m.PlanDate, 106), ' ', '-') AS ManagmentPlanDate
FROM    ManagmentPlan m
WHERE   m.ProductID IN ( SELECT Product_ID
                         FROM   Product
                         WHERE  C_ID IN ( SELECT    C_ID
                                          FROM      Category )
                                AND U_ID IN ( SELECT    U_ID
                                              FROM      Units ) )
        AND m.PrescribedBy IN ( SELECT  Emp_no
                                FROM    Employee )
        AND m.IssueStockID IN ( SELECT  Serial_No
                                FROM    Issue_Stock )
        AND ( ( @PatientID IS NULL )
              AND ( @VisitID IS NULL )
              AND ( m.WardRegNo = @WardRegNo )
            )
        OR --Get only cuurent admission TP 
        ( ( @PatientID IS NULL )
          AND ( @WardRegNo IS NULL )
          AND ( VisitID = @VisitID
                AND m.WardRegNo IS NULL
              )
        )
        OR -- Get Only Current OPD visit TP 
        ( ( @WardRegNo IS NULL )
          AND ( @VisitID IS NULL )
          AND ( visitid IN ( SELECT id
                             FROM   PatientVisit
                             WHERE  PatientID = @PatientID ) )
        )
        OR --Get All Visits TP
        ( ( @PatientID IS NULL )
          AND ( @VisitID IS NOT NULL )
          AND ( @WardRegNo IS NOT NULL )
          AND ( ( VisitID = @VisitID )
                OR ( m.WardRegNo = @WardRegNo )
              )
        ) -- Get Current OPD visit and cuurent admission TP (Both)
        AND m.Deleted != 1
        AND m.PatientDeptID = @PatientDeptID
GROUP BY REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), m.PlanDate, 106), ' ', '-')
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), m.PlanDate, 106), ' ', '-') AS DATETIME) DESC
```

[image]

Although, it solved my problem of speed or optimization of the query, but just was curious as to what exactly is the difference between those two queries, as I thought the first one translates to the second one...

**UPDATE - I**
As you can see, both queries differ in only the **JOINS** converted to **IN** statements...

Comment: What do the execution plans look like? They aren't guaranteed to return the same number of rows dependant on your data. Also if you have a trusted FK then the second one might not need to access `category` at all.

Comment: @MartinSmith: +1, and a trusted FK also means that the first one doesn't need the join.

Comment: @AndriyM - Agreed. The comment was made when the first one was selecting columns from `Category`

Comment: @MartinSmith: Ah, I see, it didn't occur to me to look at the revision history. Other comments, as well as the answers, make now more sense too. Thanks.

Comment: Do the posted queries have the performance issues?

Comment: I don't know why people have down voted the question so much. All I wanted to ask was that what is happening behind the scene for the two queries. Why is the first query a lot faster than the second query...

Comment: `@`NaveedButt - You changed the question since asking it which pretty much invalidated @Lieven's answer and have supplied **no** additional details that would allow anyone to answer it anyway  (table structures, cardinality of tables, execution plan, real query).

Comment: @NaveedButt - my downvote was due to everything you left out and the lack of response on all the questions asked by Martin and me through comments on my answer. With hindsight, I now feel like an <fill in your favorite curse> about that. I'll revert the downvote but you **have** to provide additional information for anyone to be able to help **you**.

Comment: @MartinSmith I have updated the execution plan and the queries above. Kindly see if they meean any sense to you...

Comment: @NaveedButt - You seem to be missing indexes. As a quick test, can you add indexes on `ManagmentPlan.ProductID`, `Product.C_ID`, `ManagmentPlan.PrescribedBy`, `ManagementPlan.IssueStockID` and `Product.U_ID`, run the queries and let us know the results?

Comment: @Lieven Thanks for your suggetion. I will put the indexes in the query. All I wanted to know was, what makes the second query run faster? :(

Comment: @NaveedButt - Because you don't have the right indexes. Adding the right indexes might very well make your first query perform better than your second. You might then want to know what makes the first query run faster... there's a certain pattern here <g>.

Comment: @Lieven Yeah, I would and shouldn't I be? I just wanted to know about the details of how the query is run at the back end...

Comment: @NaveedButt - Absolutely nothing wrong with a healthy dose of curiosity and a willingness to learn but for questions like this, there's no firesure way to say why a statement performs better than another one. It depends on a multitude of factors where indexing is just one of them. Other factors can include: Current load, Out-dated statistics, Network-latency, the phase of the moon *(ok, that's not true <g>)*...

Comment: @Lieven I believe the factors you have mentioned are for both of the queries, aren't they?

Comment: @NaveedButt - True but current load can be minimal while executing query1 and maximal with query2. Out-dated statistics migh impact both queries differently. Did you try adding those indexes? What were the results?

Answer (score 2):

For one, your first statement retrieves all matching records from **both** the `Products` and `Category` tables whereas your second statement only retrieves all matching rows from `Products`.

What is the performance difference if you change your first statement to

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   Products p
       INNER JOIN Category c ON p.CatNo = c.CatNo
```

**Edit**

*(as mentioned by Martin)* note that the number of rows is only identical for both statements if `CatNo` is unique in the `Category` table. The `INNER JOIN` will return as many records as there are in the `Category` table whereas the `IN` statement will return as many records as there are unique `CatNo` in the `Category` table.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. Can't understand fully... :(

Comment: @NaveedButt - I'm not sure how to explain it a bit more other than that those two statements do no return the same amount of data. The number of rows is the same for both but not the number of columns.

Comment: Number of rows is only guaranteed to be the same under the (reasonable) assumption of no duplicate category numbers in Category

Comment: @MartinSmith - I didn't think of that, thx. I have added this information to the answer.

Comment: basically my query is something like the one you have mentioned in your answer. It retrieves only one column from the database. I am going to update my description as well

Comment: @NaveedButt - That's a world of difference, can you show us both your execution plans?

Comment: I am sorry for that, but I cannot show you my original query as it is confidential. That is a query that is a replica of the original query..., but with minimum stuff :)

Comment: So what else have you left out? How many tables are involved? Have you verified same number of rows from both? What join types in both plans?

Comment: @NaveedButt - *(I never understood how a query can be confidential but that's me. Data? Sure! But the query?)* I would advise you to look at both execution plans, note the differences and post only those differences to SO.

Comment: @MartinSmith I haven't left out anything else

Comment: @NaveedButt - What about all the other questions asked by Martin and me?

Comment: I have changed the queries above with the real queries and added the exeecution plans as well. Kindly see if you can help me on this...

Answer (score 0):

An in clause filters the rows that come back from product.  An inner join adds columns from category to the select statement output.